# Is it possible to include a .dll in a c++ compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, dll

Hey so I'm using vscode as my IDE and I was wondering if it was possible to include the dll for glfw3 into my build as whenever I run the finished program I need the glfw3.dll in the same folder as the .exe for it to run. Does anybody know how I would add it and if it is even possible.
Also here is my .vscode tasks.json

```
    {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-static",
                "-g",
                "-std=c++17",
                "${file}",
                "-I",
                "./include",
                "-L",
                "./lib",
                "-lopengl32",
                "-lglew32",
                "-lglfw3dll",
                "-Wl,--subsystem,windows",
                "-o",
               "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe" 
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
```

Comment: You need to use a _post-build command_.  I have no experience doing it in vscode. Maybe this link will help: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1276983/How-to-implement-pre-post-build-event-in-VS-code.

Comment: DLLs are usually searched within environment variable PATH

Answer (score 0):

You can use a build event to copy the DLL into your exe target directory or put the DLL in your PATH environment variable.